# How to detect if Kivy has camera installed?

Tags: python, camera, kivy

If there are no camera subsystems installed, then Kivy crashes when parsing the camera widget of `examples/camera.py` demo.   Instead of crashing, is there a call to see if a camera provider would be found?

Here is the trace:

```
[DEBUG             ] [Camera      ] Ignored <avfoundation> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Camera      ] Ignored <opencv> (import error)
[CRITICAL          ] [Camera      ] Unable to find any valuable Camera provider at all!
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "camera.py", line 33, in <module>
     CameraApp().run()
   File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/app.py", line 766, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "camera.py", line 29, in build
     return Builder.load_string(kv)
   File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 1522, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 1704, in _apply_rule
     e))
 kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 7:
 ...
       5:    Camera:
       6:        id: camera
 >>    7:        resolution: 399, 299
       8:
       9:    BoxLayout:
 ...
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your call initial in a `try:..except` block:

```
camera_available = False
try:
    cam = kivy.camera()
except TypeError:
    cam = None
if not cam is None and not cam.__camera is None: # Experiment has shown both checks are needed
    camera_available = True
# Anything that tries to use cam now needs to check camera_available
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.   As some odd side effect of the cascading errors:  1) the 'critical error' is reported as a side effect of importing kivy.uix.camera.Camera; 2) creating a camera object does not make an error.  3) setting the resolution to [-1, -1] does not make an error.  4) play=True or play=False does not make an error.  Even displaying a camera widget does not make an error, but just a blank screen.  Only trying to set the non-existant camera to a specific value makes an error.

Comment: It looks like I can cheat and look at the cam._camera to see if it is None.

Comment: If you don't mind _given that you did the work_ I will add that to the answer above to preserve it for others.

Comment: @CharlesMerriam I have included it in the answer above but would suggest raising a ticket on kivy, (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues), requesting addition of a cameras_available member.

Comment: Thanks.  I added a ticket.  Turns out the cam._camera hack won't work when changing the index of the camera.  Bug #2222 points out that the _camera is only set when resolutions are not the default.   I'll dig into a good routine soonish and put it a new camera demo in January.